# How to invert the legend's on-click--behavior on XY chart in amcharts4?

Tags: amcharts4

I have this issue. The default behavior of XY amchart is to load all data, and on legend click - hide the current selection. Is it possible to revert this behavior?
Like, if I select a legend- to hide all the other elements from the chart and leave the current selection.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar may be strange with the help of a translator because of the weak English.

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.togglable = false;
```

The code above deactivates the basic behavior of the legend.

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
                let targetName = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name;
                chart.series.each(function (item) {
                    if(targetName != item.name){
                        item.disabled = true;
                    }
                });
});
```

The code above is an event when you click the legend.

I don't know if it's the answer you want, but I wrote it down...